# How to e2e test an Angular app with Firebase authentication and Firestore using cypress

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, cypress

I have an Angular app that uses Firebase Authentication for logging in and then reading and writing data to a Firestore database. I want to do some e2e tests for it.

I would rather write the tests with mocked data or a local server.

I haven't found any local way of running Firestore so far.
I saw that you can stub out methods with cy.stub, but it's unclear to me how to do that with Angular2. How do I get a hold of the object that I want to stub out methods in? In the real code they are dependency injected in the constructor

Or what is the preferred way of writing Cypress e2e test with Angular and Firebase (AngularFire2)? Any good recommendations?

Thanks

Comment: It is unfortunate that the `cy.stub()` examples are a bit fragmentary. In the case of angularfire2, it is unlikely you can stub firestore in the same way as unit tests do. I did find this code fragment (with no explanatory notes) [Recipe for Firebase authentication](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/issues/118). It uses Firebase command line tool to redirect data to /cypress/fixtures.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase doesn't provide any local implementation; it consists of (I presume) a large body of proprietary code that runs on Google's servers.

But for an isolated search environment, you can use a second Firebase database, a separate one from your real production Firebase. We do this by using Angular CLI "environments" (recently renamed "configurations"). With this mechanism you can have a different firebase configuration available when running your tests, versus what you use for real deployment.

I realize this does not provide the answer you're looking for, something that runs fully locally; but it works reasonably well, and is easy to set up.

(Also, this has nothing to do with Cypress...  the above works equally well with Protractor.)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I recently had a similar problem (I think) and came up with a solution which has worked quite nicely so far.

If AngularFire2 is strongly typed, you could wrap your application's access to it in a service and then try writing a simple stub of that service which returns an object that follows the same interface as the AngularFire2 service.

Then you can use Angular's dependency injection and environment files to run your e2e tests against the stubbed version.

Because it is type safe and relies on AngularFire2's own typings, if they change then your stub will stop compiling and you will have to update it (which is good!).

You can also use TypeScript's `partial` keyword to only implement the bits of the interface that you care about, meaning that you don't have to stub everything, only the bits that you rely on in your code.

I've written a brief guide to this approach here:

http://wtfisanapi.com/htf-do-i-write-e2e-tests-with-a-stubbed-dependency-angular-nrwl-nx-edition/

with the full source code for the demo here:

https://github.com/robt1019/e2e-stub-demo

I'm not very familiar with Firebase or Firestore, but I have used this approach successfully to run e2e tests against a stubbed version of a library that does a bunch of networking type tasks.

What did you end up doing?